# Add one element to the DOM at every iteration not all at the end of the loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, dom

I'm not a pure front end developer and I wonder why, in a loop where at every iteration an element is added to the DOM, the resulting DOM is only visible at the end of the loop and not progressively.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
</body>
<script>
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: They do get added one at a time. The browser just waits for you to stop before repainting.

Comment: Because JavaScript can count to 1000000 pretty quickly and browser re-draws take time?

Comment: Simple answer, is because the DOM is "repaintet" on ticks, when the javascript engine has completed the synchronous tasks and can update the DOM. More accurate answer, has to do with implementations, microtasks, event loop and optimization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript runs code to completion before the repaint events get processed. So in order to get the display updated at regular times, you need to end the script execution at regular times and put something in the event queue that will call back your function for proceeding further.

For instance, you can do this with `setTimeout`:

```js
(function loop(i) {
    if (i > 10000) return; // end condition
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    void document.body.offsetWidth;
    setTimeout(loop.bind(null, i+1), 0);
})(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is progressively added, probably the iteration is enough fast and you cannot see in console what is happening...

There are no auto-optimization, you need to take care of performances...

```js
function TestCtrl() {
  var body = document.body;
  var child = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('div');
    c.className = 'child';

    return c;
  };
  
  
  function Logger() {
    console.log('log new element');
  };
  document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", Logger);
  
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log('adding element', i);
    body.appendChild(child());
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', TestCtrl);
```

```css
.child {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: yellow;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
  background: pink;
}
```